# creating a component when i click button, Angular 13

Tags: angular

how to create a component when i click a button using Angular 13
the way i tried is using ViewChild and ComponentFactoryResolver still confused
is there any other way

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  Inject,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('appenHere', {static : false, read : ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  addNewComponent() {
    let childComponent = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(NewTileComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(childComponent); // <-- here it's throws an error!
  } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For Angular v13 and higher

In `Angular v13` the `ComponentResolveFactory` was marked as deprecated and will be removed in `v16`.

New way of dynamic creating components was introduced.

Here is a code example:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('appenHere', {static : false, read : ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor() { }

  addNewComponent() {
    this.target.createComponent(NewTileComponent);
  } 
}
```